# Inconsistent Accessibility base class error

Tags: c#, java, android, visual-studio, xamarin

Hi I'm running sample code from Xamarin on VS2013. It has to deal with Java Bindings. I'm getting three errors upon building and they're all about inconsistent accessibility.

Inconsistent accessibility: base class 'Org.Osmdroid.Tileprovider.Modules.MapTileModuleProviderBase.TileLoader' is less accessible than class 'Org.Osmdroid.Tileprovider.Modules.MapTileDownloader.TileLoader'

The other errors are the same except the last line is a different class.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What part of the error message don't you understand? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx

Comment: Looks like you're trying to bind OSMDroid?  There is an example here: https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/OsmDroidBindingExample (Note that this isn't bound to the most recent version of OSMDroid)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accessibility can only be tightened not loosened, so from the top of the inheritance hierarchy to the bottom only these changes are allowed:

> public --> protected
>
> protected --> private

Obviously, a `class` cannot be `private`. But there is also the `internal` access modifier which removes a class's definition from the assembly's manifest, thus providing a cleaner API to the consumer.

To fix the problem you must assign to the class

```
Org.Osmdroid.Tileprovider.Modules.MapTileDownloader.TileLoader            (say D)
```

an access modifier that is *AT LEAST* as tight as that of

```
Org.Osmdroid.Tileprovider.Modules.MapTileModuleProviderBase.TileLoader    (say P)
```

If `P` is internal, `D` must be internal, too.
If `P` is public, `D` may be internal or public.

Comment: So essentially I should change all occurrences of public to private? If so the errors are still existent.

Answer (score 4):

You will need to modify the Metadata.xml on the binding library. Try if this takes care of the first problem:

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='org.osmdroid.tileprovider.modules']/class[@name='MapTileModuleProviderBase.TileLoader']" name="visibility">public</attr>
```

Comment: @ user2402616: That's actually a good thing, that means that the previous errors are fixed out, you are seeing issues that were obscured by your initial problem. Binding is a painful long labor in some cases. Last time I finished an AAR binding I ended up with a 98 line long metadata.xml file. So gather all your patience and keep going